# Can't connect Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK with Asterisk

Tags: c#, asterisk, sip, ozeki

I have installed asterisk 11 on Ubuntu 14 using vmware. I am trying to develop a softphone using c# and Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK but for some reasons i can't connect my softphone to register with asterisk. I have also tried Ozeki demo Softphone but still getting the same results. **X-Lite and other softphones work fine**. I have also used Wireshark to see whats going on. In the Wireshark log, i have seen that there is no sip protocol in x-lite sofphone but in ozeki demo softphone there is sip protocol.
-Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Do Asterisk and the virtual machine run on the same Linux? In this case it is conceivable that the log contains nothing. You may try to register to a remote Asterisk server. This [guide](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_125-asterisk-pbx-setup-voip.html) can help you to setup the SDK with Asterisk.

Comment: I did follow the guide, but nothing seems to work. I am using windows 8.1 x64.